# Creating a map GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a GUI that can read and display "map files". The map files are just text files containg a long list of integers, representing the height above sea level. The user should initially just be able to browse for a text file an hit "Display" or something, which generates a colorfull image

I'm trying to descide what language and libraries to achieve this. Is python + tkinker a way of doing this? Does this sound like a difficult problem?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by drawing on a tkinter canvas. However, to generate nice looking plots with less effort, you can also display matplotlib plots inside a tkinter app.

See for example [embedding_in_tk.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and [embedding_in_tk2.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html) from the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/).

[image]